# If statement keeps looping - c

Tags: c, function, loops, if-statement

So I'm trying to finish off this program and all I need to do is implement some form of user input for this card game but so far everything I've tried just loops endlessly (or until I run out of elements in the array) and I don't know what I'm doing wrong as logically when I look at my code it seems to make sense.

```
void players(int deck[])
{
    int x;
    int a; 

    a = 1;

     printf("Player 1 \n"); 
     printf("Your Hand is: \n"); 
     draw(deck, a);
     draw(deck, a);
     while(a = 1)
     {
     printf("What would you like to do: Press 1 to Draw. 2 to Stay. \n"); 
     scanf("%d" , &x); 
     if(x = 1)
     {
          draw(deck, a);
     }
     else
     {
         a--;
     }
     }
}
```

This is the input in question

```
void draw(int deck[SIZE], int a)
{
    int numCards = 10;
    int i; 
    int hand[numCards];
    int card;
    for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++)
    {
        card = deck[top-1];     
        hand[i] = card; 
        top--;   
    }
    if(a != 0)
    printcards(card);
    else
    for(i = 0; i < numCards && top > 0; i++)
    printcards(card);

}
```

This is the function the Loop works with to draw cards (printcards is a separate function that only prints off the cards) players calls draw and it works but as stated it will endlessly call cards even when I press 2 (which is suppose to quit). So I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try `while (x == 1`) instead. Same for `while (a == 1)`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code, line by line, attempting to execute it in your head, reading each statement out loud?

Comment: I disagree that this should be closed as localized?  It's a common beginner mistake.  Perhaps I am missing something here?

Answer (score 6):

`while(a = 1)`

Assigning `1` into `a` will cause this to loop forever.  You should use `==` instead for the comparison.  Please turn on compiler warnings and fix them as they would have easily caught this case.

BTW, you have the same error with your `if(x = 1)` statement as well...

Answer (score 2):

You don't check equality (operator `==`), you actually assign value(operator `=`).

`if(x = 1){}` is equivalent to `x = 1; if(x) {}`

And `if (x)` is equivalent to `if(x != 0)` for integers

Comment: BTW, this is a labeled a C question so I'm not sure if the operator syntax you use above is correct.  I would love to be corrected if I am wrong about it though.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, yes, in C you can somewhere in code write `operator ==`(for example define it) but it's still operator so I wouldn't say it's incorrect in text